# What are the physical properties of energy?

Tags: energy

I'm trying to get my head around what energy actualy is, i.e. what are its physical properties?
I understand the definition that energy is the ability to do work, however what actually is it?..
eg. If we look at an electromagnetic energy, it moves in a wave, but what phyiscal thing is moving in a wave?
Many thanks to any responders.